# To count no of rows in django database table and display them in index?

Tags: python, django, database, count

How to count number of rows from a django table name Item having two columns and display it on index page using views

Model:-

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_id =models.IntegerField()
    category=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views.py file, define the view function that retrieves the count of rows from the Item table:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Item

def index(request):
    # Get the count of rows in the Item table
    item_count = Item.objects.count()

    # Pass the count value to the template using the context dictionary
    context = {
        'item_count': item_count
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Create an HTML template named index.html in your app's templates directory to display the count value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Number of Rows in Item Table: {{ item_count }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```